# How can I host multiple applications with Apache2?

Tags: angular, apache2, raspberry-pi4

I have a Raspberry Pi 4 which is currently running an Angular website fine in the standard Apache /var/www/html folder. This website is then perfectly accessible when I hit the URL from another device.

What I would like to do is host multiple different Angular apps, ideally in separate folders inside the html folder - if possible. One of the problems here is that I don't have any domains or certificate for https and I'd just like to run the apps in http and take whatever risk.

I guess I would need to 'map' these folder/apps to port numbers? This is where I'm clueless really as I've never used apache2 before. Can anybody please advise how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use different ports for the applications. Create subfolder for each application under the `/var/www/html` folder (the subfolders can be named freely):

```
/var/www/html
├── app1
├── app2
├── app3
├── ...
```

Then, when building each application from the angular source code, add `base-href`-argument to set target directory under the web server root. For example, with app1 you would use

```
ng build --base-href /app1/
```

After that your different apps can be found in `http://yourserver/app1/`, `http://yourserver/app2/` etc.